# Fire Javascript method after server side action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a submit button. When I click it, post back call happens. That's fine. I have caught the button click event with jQuery and did some action also.

When I click the button, jQuery method executes first. Then the server side method.

Is there a way to execute the jQuery after returning from server side?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Extract File" name="btnExtract" id="btnExtract" style="float: left;margin-left:10px"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#btnExtract').on('click', function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("FileProcess","Einmaliger")';
  $.get(url, {x:'are'}, function (data) {
    alert('waited 5 sec!');
  });
});
```

**Server Side**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Einmaliger(Einmaliger einmaliger)
{
  //Some code...
}
```

Comment: Any source code available?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Sir, Source code ? And which language u are working on C,C++,VB? Can i know?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up as an AJAX request in jQuery and have an event handler on the Ajax's "done" event. This will mean that your submit will also need to return a value to your ajax request.